# How To Deselect (Unfocus) All gameObjects in a Unity Scene View?

Tags: unity, level-design

When I'm done with moving and rotating gameObjects in a Unity scene, I want to deselect everything to not accidentally change it. How?

In some applications ESC key does the trick, in others 'D' (deselect) comes to rescue. But I don't know any remedy in Unity. My workaround is that I click somewhere in the Project View (I don't like this approach because it brings up the inspector for that asset).

Answer (score 2):

You could click on a blank area in the scene view, or in the hierarchy, or if you really really want a keyboard shortcut you could add a custom editor script: (Untested)

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

static class DeselectEverything() {
  [MenuItem("Edit/Select None _d")]
  //alternatively MenuItem("Edit/Select None _ESC")] although it may be _ESCAPE
  static void DoSelectNothing() {
    Selection.objects = new Object[0];
  }
}
```

You can take look at [the Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MenuItem.html) to see more about how to use MenuItem, specifically how to organize the item within the Edit menu and how to give it a different keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

The hotkey to deselect all GameObjects in a Unity Scene is

`Shift + D`

Also you could use the action from the menu `Edit` then choose `Deselect All`.

Unity 2020.3.16f1